# Topologically, what is $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with a line and conic removed?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

This is probably straightforward but I'm having trouble figuring out what topological space I have if it's constructed in the following way. Consider a generic degree 1 complex homogeneous polynomial on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and let $L$ denote it's zero locus. Similarly, let $C$ be the zero locus of a generic degree 2 complex homogeneous polynomial. By Bezout's Theorem, there are two intersection points.

Let's suppose that the two intersection points are in fact, in the real part of $\mathbb{CP}^2$. So if we remove $L$ and $C$ from $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and then examine the real part, this should be some manifold $M$ with two connected components. It seems that $M$ could be two disks or two Möbius bands but I don't know how to determine which it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=\{z=0\}$ and $C=\{xy=z^2\}$, so the two curves intersect at $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$. Then

$$\mathbb R\mathbb P^2\setminus (L\bigcup C)=\mathbb R^2\setminus \{xy=1\}$$

which has three connected components.